# Pick random element from set with non-uniform distribution?

Tags: java, data-structures, random, set

I would like to have a set and have its elements have probabilities associated with them, so when I pick an element at random from the set, the distribution follows the probabilities associated with the elements. I would like to use that in a very small Java application that stores a list of movies I want to watch so I can have it suggest a random movie to me (I always take hours to pick a movie otherwise). With each movie I want to associate the number of times the movie was suggested to me, which will be inversely proportionate to the probability that the movie is picked from the list for the next suggestion.

Is there a data structure that allows picking elements from it at random with a non-uniform distribution?

If not, what's the most efficient way of writing such a data structure? I could of course always build an array, put every element of the list into the array often enough so the distribution of values in the array matches up the probabilities I want them to have, and pick a random element from that array; but for large sets of movies, that's gonna be terribly inefficient. Another idea I had was encapsulating the element and the sum of probabilities of all elements up to it (so the first element would be encapsulated as (first, p(first)), the second as (second, p(second) + p(first)) and so on), then pick a random number between 0 and 1 and do a binary search on a sorted list of those encapsulated elements. Does that sound sensible?

TL:DR (and somewhat abstract): how do I map a non-uniform distribution to the elements of a set efficiently in Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure I understood the question correct. I would use a `TreeMap<Double, Movie>`.

Example: lets say you have Movie A (60 %), Movie B (30 %) and Movie C (10 %).

```
TreeMap<Double, Movie> movies = new TreeMap<>();
movies.put(0.6, new Movie("Movie A"));
movies.put(0.9, new Movie("Movie B")); // 0.6 + 0.3
movies.put(1.0, new Movie("Movie C")); // 0.6 + 0.3 + 0.1
Double probability = Math.random(); // between 0 (inclusive) and 1.0 (exclusive)
Movie chosen = movies.higherEntry(probability).getValue();
```

I'll leave the population and rearranging of the probabilities up to you.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed; just have to wait a couple of minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: This, but `TreeMap` seems to be overkill. You can do the same with single iteration - skip until sum of probabilities is bigger then the random number.

Comment: @zch: what do you mean by single iteration? I'm not iterating over anything. And what do you mean with overkill? My lookup will work in `O(log n)` while iterating sounds like `O(n)`.

Comment: @zch That would be linear for every time I pick a value from the set; using a tree map I just need O(n log n) for population and then O(log n) for picking a value.

Comment: But this solution makes it necessary to rebuild a tree every time something is changed, so `O(n lg n)` may be significant. I thought about same solution as Jonathan Dautrich. To have both changes and choices in `O(lg n)` is certainly possible, but I guess simple custom tree structure would be necessary.

Comment: @zch I don't think we can get below O(n) with updating the keys since I want them to be inversely proportional to the number of times the movie was recommended, so the probabilities for all movies will have to be recalculated after every pick. However the tree won't have to be re-balanced, so it remains at O(log n) lookup for every pick.

Comment: @G.Bach It is possible - almost full binary tree, where each node knows sum of unscaled probabilities under it. Choice is randomly going down and updating is just updating a single path.

Answer (score 3):

There's a cool method called "the alias method" that enables picking in O(1).
Beutifully explained here: http://pandasthumb.org/archives/2012/08/lab-notes-the-a.html

Answer (score 2):

I would simply define:

```
class Movie {
    int recommendations;
}
```

then do

```
public Movie chooseMovie(ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int sum = 0;
    for(Movie movie : movies) {
        sum += movie.recommendations;
    }
    int choice = rand.nextInt(sum);
    int soFar = 0;
    for(Movie movie : movies) {
        soFar += movie.recommendations;
        if(choice < soFar) {
            return movie;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The choice variable is more likely to fall within a movie's recommendation range if that range is larger. It's slow, but in practice the number of movies is probably small enough for it to work fine for you. If you're doing a lot of lookups, you can cache the total recommendation sum and the incremental sum, similar to the way you suggested.

### Edit - Probability Inversely Proportional to Number of Recommendations

```
public Movie chooseMovie(ArrayList<Movie> movies) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    double sum = 0;
    for(Movie movie : movies) {
        if(movie.recommendations > 0) {
            sum += 1 / (double) (movie.recommendations);
        }
    }
    int choice = rand.nextDouble() * sum;
    double soFar = 0;
    for(Movie movie : movies) {
        if(movie.recommendations > 0) {
            soFar += 1 / (double) (movie.recommendations);
            if(choice < soFar) {
                return movie;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: +1, that's what I had in mind, so thanks for code :) This is (in terms of big-O) probably as efficient as the tree map, since I have to update the number of times a movie was recommended every time I pick one, so every pick is in O(n) to readjust the keys in the tree map.

Comment: Hm thinking a little more about it, this will not make the movies that were recommended multiple times less probable, but more probable, so that the recommendations at some point converge against a singe movie.

Comment: You're welcome. I think there's a clever way to cache partial sums within a tree structure so that so that both update and lookup take time O(log n), but it's probably not worth it unless you have a ton of movies.

Comment: So you actually prefer to watch less recommended movies? I guess I don't understand.

Comment: Yeah there is a pretty straightforward way to augment an ordered tree to do that; but you're right, that's way overkill for what I have in mind.

Comment: Ah sorry, I probably didn't explain my intent clearly enough; I want it that movies that had rarely been recommended before will be more likely to be recommended in the future, so when I have a streak of movies that I don't want to watch and just keep clicking "pick random movie", the movies I click away are less likely to be suggested again.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misread that. My edited version should do it. The problem is that it ignores movies with 0 past recommendations. Based on your definition, they have infinite probability over other movies, so we should probably keep them separate and recommend all of them first.

Comment: Ah very good, I couldn't come up with something sensible myself - but it's very straightforward, thank you!