# getting the most 'diverse' set of pairs from a list in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, combinations, probability

I have a list in python of length N and I want to choose K pairs of elements from it, where repetition of elements within a pair is not allowed and where `(x,y) == (y,x)` (order insensitive).  There are N choose 2 pairs possible, and K is always significantly smaller than N.  What is a good *deterministic* (no sampling) way to pick the most 'diverse' and representative set of pairs from the list, meaning: (1) set of pairs where highest number of items from the list is represented (and there's not a bias for any particular element), (2) and where the list of pairs is not biased towards the start or end of the list?

example:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

there are 5 choose 2 = 10 combinations possible. If we ask for 2 pairs (K = 2), a **good** set of pairs would be `[(1,2),(3,4)]` because almost every element appears in the list and we don't have repetitions of any element. A **bad** set of pairs for K = 2 would be: `[(1,2),(1,3)]` since it's reusing the 1 element and is clearly biased towards the start of list. If K were > 2 in this case we'd need to repeat elements, it's inevitable, but I want to find a way to do this that is representative/diverse wrt list.

I'm just looking for an efficient and simple heuristic, does not have have to be perfect. any ideas?

happy to use numpy/scipy for this.

Comment: 5! / (2!(5 - 2)!) = 10

Comment: @aaronman No, you go (n!)/ (k! (n-k)!). At question: Count how often each item appears in the list, assign probabilities according to multiplicity for each number. Fix an order on the set of items (no duplicates there) and pick from that ordered list items according to their probability. Adjust multiplicities after each pick, rinse and repeat. A similar question [I once had](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915899/pick-random-element-from-set-with-non-uniform-distribution) might help you.

Comment: Or just [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=5+choose+2). More seriously though, what's the reason for being deterministic? Would it be enough to do a shuffle with a known seed?

Comment: @Paulo: google what? shuffle with a known seed is okay it's just not a great solution when K is significantly smaller than N choose 2 and you can afford to guarantee that you won't have to repeat elements

Comment: @user248237dfsf Sorry, the google suggestion was about 5 choose 2 being 10 (and it was just a joke anyway).

Comment: Do you not want a random approach because you need repeatability, or because you don't know how to do it without shuffling the entire list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least pseudo-random sampling of some kind or else there will always be some sort of "bias" when you re-run your pair sampling code, whether toward the beginning or end, or somewhere else.  If K is smaller than N/2, and if N is not too large (say 100 million or less) then you can use the following python code, which avoids repetitive sampling calls because it generates K psuedo-random pairs all at once, avoiding duplicates

```
import random

X = range(N)

random.seed() # uses system time to initialize random number generator, or you can pass in a deterministic seed as an argument if you want

# code to use to generate K pairs
A = random.sample(X,2*K) # now you have a list of 2*K unique elements from 0 to N-1
pairs = zip(A[0:K],A[K:(2*K)]) # now you have your pairs
```

Now, if K is greater than N/2 then you will have to have duplicates, but you can minimize duplicates similar to above, by simply rerunning code similar to the 2 lines above in a loop.  If N is odd this creates headaches but a simple very close approximate strategy is to repeatedly generate floor(N/2) pairs (avoiding duplicates) and just leave one number unused each time.  Code follows:

```
pairs = []
M = N
if M % 2 == 1:
  M -= 1
while len(pairs) < K:
  B = random.sample(X,M)
  A = zip(B[0:(M/2)],B[(M/2):M])
  pairs.extend(A)
pairs = pairs[0:K]
```

Comment: Note you don't have to initialize X = range(N), X can be any list of length N if you already have one

Answer (score 0):

Take the first K matches from a [round-robin tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm)? Permute the list by a pseudorandom Fisher–Yates shuffle with a deterministic seed to avoid bias toward the ends.

Comment: @user248237dfsf No, I don't.