# Random numbers and percentages in Java

Tags: java, random

I have some Java code. In my code, I have a collection of users. Each user has a percentage chance of "winning" the collection, as that the sum of the chance of each user in the collection is 100. To choose a winner, I sort the collection (which is an array) in ascending order. My problem is choosing the winner based off of that sorted array. This is what I have tried:

```
public Bet getWinner() {
    double random = Math.random() * 100;

    Bet[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(getBets(), bets.size());
    Arrays.sort(copy);

    for (Bet bet : copy) {
        if (random < getChance(bet)) {
            return bet;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public float getChance(Bet bet) {
    return (bet.getAmount() / getJackpotTotal()) * 100;
}

public float getJackpotTotal() {
    float total = 0;

    for (Bet bet : getBets()) {
        total += bet.getAmount();
    }
    return total;
}
```

But is there are two users in the collection, one with 10% chance of winning and the other with 90%, if `random` is > 90, `getWinner` returns `null`. How else can I do this? Is there a way to create a random distribution based off of a percentage, or is there something simpler or different?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

This is not a duplicate because it is not asking specifically about weighted random numbers. It is asking about choosing something (not a random number) *from* a random number.

Comment: For the `n`-th user, sum up all probabilities from user `0` to `n` (this is guaranteed to be between `0` and `1` by definition). If this sum is `<` or `<=` (your decision) than `random`, you have found your winner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weighted randomness in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737283/weighted-randomness-in-java)

Comment: @pjs: Not a duplicate because it's not asking specifically about weighted randomness, but choosing something based from a percentage

Comment: Perhaps you like this one better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915899/pick-random-element-from-set-with-non-uniform-distribution  This is definitely a question that has been answered before.

Comment: Unlike that question, this is asking using a uniform distribution @pjs

Comment: @LAB No, 90%/10% is not a uniform distribution.  [The *definition* of a uniform distribution is that all outcomes are equally likely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable that keeps a total of the odds you've gone through so far:

```
int total = 0;
for (Bet bet : copy) {

    if (random < total + getChance(bet)) {
        return bet;
    }
    total += getChance(bet);
}
```

Your naming conventions are a little ambiguous, so I hope you get the idea even if I may be a bit inaccurate with the proper names.

Comment: Yeah, I could definitely work on names. But your code makes enough sense, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider the summed up chances. If one player has chance 90 and one 10, then you first compare < 90 and then < 90 + 10.

Comment: Well, after realizing that was all I had to do, excuse me a moment, I'm dropping out of math. But thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Now that I am in industry, I do not have too much opportunity to show off with my PhD in maths ;-)